# Avoid adding attribute class empty if the condition is false

Tags: jquery

I have a few conditions of links: If the location of `href` is x, the function add a `class` with `name` "marked". The problem of that the function **is adding me empty class to the other false conditions**, so I want to delete the empty class on the false condition. Example:

True condition:

```
<li class="nav-item "><a href="/biblioteca/buzon-sugerencias" class="marked">Buzón de sugerencias</a> </li>
```

False condition:

```
<li class="nav-item "><a href="/biblioteca/authors" class="">Autores</a></li>
```

JQuery script of the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.match('residenciarucab.es/biblioteca/books')){
        $(".nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("marked");
    }
    if(window.location.href.match('residenciarucab.es/biblioteca/authors')){
        $(".nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("marked");
    }
    if(window.location.href.match('residenciarucab.es/biblioteca/buzon-sugerencias')){
        $(".nav-item:nth-child(3) a").addClass("marked");
    }
    if(window.location.href.match('residenciarucab.es/biblioteca/desiderata')){
        $(".nav-item:nth-child(4) a").addClass("marked");
    }
        if(window.location.href.match('residenciarucab.es/biblioteca/book')){
        $(".nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("marked");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tested your code inside my console and i didn't get any empty class attributes. Can you please create a fiddle where you reproduce the error, so that we can debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `removeAttribute` to remove class attribute as

```
document.querySelector('.nav-item:nth-child(1) a').removeAttribute("class");
```

or in jquery `removeAttr` use

```
$('.nav-item:nth-child(1) a').removeAttr('class');
```

```js
//document.querySelector('.nav-item:nth-child(1) a').removeAttribute("class");
$('.nav-item:nth-child(1) a').removeAttr('class');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="nav-item "><a href="/biblioteca/authors" class="">Autores</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so I need to make removeattr line for each false class?